# Does the lastFM api provide youtube links?

Tags: api, last.fm

I am making an android application which lists trending songs. I am fetching the song details through the LastFM API. The API method I use is http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=track.getInfo&api_key=YOUR_API_KEY&artist=cher&track=believe&format=json

However, this doesn't give me a link to YouTube like how LastFM does on their website. Is there any way for me to replicate that functionality? Am I supposed to use another API method that I don't know of or should i rely on something else entirely?

I did some amount of searching and I came across http://downloadmarkt.be/lastfm-musicengine/example-search.php In the search results, the YouTube links are also displayed. How is the developer achieving this?

Comment: Please provide some context. For instance, why would the second link have anything to do with the first link? What do you expect to happen? Why does the first link have anything to do with YouTube? Please read this: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hi sir. I have edited the question. Hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: Much better. This isn't my area of expertise but hopefully the question is good enough that someone else can answer it now. Although I'm still not sure what this has to do with Android...

Comment: Well to be honest this is the first time I've posted to SO. Should I remove the tag?

Comment: I can see you're new, you've only got 1 reputation :P As to whether or not you should remove the tag, well as I say, this isn't my area of expertise so I don't know. Do you think it's relevant? If it's relevant, leave it, otherwise remove it.

Answer (score 0):

There are no direct links to youtube videos in the last.fm API.

The website you posted searches the links directly on youtube and not on last.fm (see the [javascript](http://downloadmarkt.be/lastfm-musicengine/js/lstfm.js) at the bottom of that script file).

Best solution that I've found: you do get a page song url in the last.fm API response,

```
<url>
   https://www.last.fm/music/Anathema/_/Fragile+Dreams
</url>
```

That page contains the youtube url. If you open the html page, you'll see something like this in there

```
data-youtube-id="CsHYSvlsDWw"
data-youtube-url="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CsHYSvlsDWw"
```

Use your favorite method for parsing webpages to get that info,

```
$ curl -sL https://www.last.fm/music/Anathema/_/Fragile+Dreams |
  hxnormalize -x 2> /dev/null |
  hxselect -s '\n' -c 'a::attr(data-youtube-id) |
  uniq
$ CsHYSvlsDWw
```

that is, you get the page, you get rid of any inconsistencies and then you select the `data-youtube-id`. You need to add a new line between the matches, since there seems to be two such entries on the page. Last step, you take one of the two similar results (the uniq part at then end).

Happy hacking.